# them can be used in a informal way?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, informal-language

> Them are two good ones, he said.

James Joyce writes this sentence. is that used in an informal way?

Comment: _Them_ for _those_  is not uncommon in some English dialects. "What are them things over there?"

Comment: What ***is*** uncommon is writing uncontracted ***are*** after the "non-standard" pronoun ***them***. In reality, most people who "misuse" ***them*** like this would probably say ***Them's** two good ones* (contracted *singular* verb form). Nearly all the rest would at least contract ***are*** to a mere schwa - normally transcribed as ***Them're** two good ones*.

Comment: Considering the context of this being in English Learners Stack Exchange, I think it's reasonable to correct your grammar. When choosing between the articles "a" or "an", we should consider the word after it. If the following word begins with a sounded consonant, you will use "a". If it starts with a vowel, you will use "an". This also applies with vowel sounds, even when it begins with a consonant(eg. "an hour" is correct, even though it begins with a consonant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Them are two good ones, he said," though found in a literary work, would *not* be used in formal English.

James Joyce is not a good reference for "standard" English. Joyce often used language in poetic and punning ways, with multiple meanings for words. To give you the flavor, here's a fairly straight-forward section of [*Finnegan' Wake*](http://www.finwake.com/ch01/ch01.htm):

> "What clashes here of wills gen wonts, oystrygods gaggin fishy-gods!
> Brékkek Kékkek Kékkek Kékkek! Kóax Kóax Kóax!"

Notice play of words, such as "wills" and "wonts" or "oystrygods" and "fishy-gods". (Do oysters have fishy-gods? Ah, *Ostrogoths* and *Visigoths*?)

And he quotes the croaking chorus from the *Frogs* of Aristophanes, where he *might* be referring indirectly to [Gilbert and Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major-General%27s_Song).

Read Joyce with dictionary, glossary and footnotes in hand (well, wouldn't them be *handnotes*?), enjoy his encyclopedic writing, peel the layers like allium, but *don't* use most of his works to learn formal *or* colloquial English. You might as well learn English from the Drake, Hoffman, and Livingston ditty, [Mairzy Doats](https://allnurseryrhymes.com/mares-eat-oats/).

Comment: "James Joyce is not a good reference for "standard" English"". That's an astute observation, and deserves to be repeated. I cannot get my heads around a _learner_ of English getting dug into Joyce - I am reminded of my own foolishness when starting to learn German and picking up Goethe, which turned out to be a _very_ bad idea.